# AWS: To Role or not to Role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html):

```
When to Create an IAM User (Instead of a Role)
...
You want to use the command-line interface (CLI) to work with AWS.

When to Create an IAM Role (Instead of a User)

- You're creating an application that runs on an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance and that application makes requests to AWS.
- You're creating an app that runs on a mobile phone and that makes requests to AWS.
- Users in your company are authenticated in your corporate network and want to be able to use AWS without having to sign in again—that is, you want to allow users to federate into AWS.
```

But it seems like companies heavily use roles for everything:

- Role for groups by creating roles with specific policies and creating custom policies to apply to groups.
- Assume role to use the CLI.
- Switch role to use different accounts.

Is that excessive or real work based solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that excessive or real work based solution?

Based on my own experience with AWS, heavily using roles is a real work based solution because, in my company, we use only roles to give access to users (yes, we have 0 users registered in your AWS environments). I'll list the reasons why we chose this way:

1. We are using [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/).

This service enables AWS Organizations with at least 3 AWS accounts to manage your organization. It'd be a mess with we had to create a user for each AWS account. Also, AWS Control Tower enables [AWS Single Sign-On](https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/).

2. We're using [AWS Single Sign-On](https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/).

This service correlates multiples AWS accounts with multiples roles with multiples users. Description:

> AWS Single Sign-On (SSO) is a cloud SSO service that makes it easy to centrally manage SSO access to multiple AWS accounts and business applications. With just a few clicks, you can enable a highly available SSO service without the upfront investment and on-going maintenance costs of operating your own SSO infrastructure. With AWS SSO, you can easily manage SSO access and user permissions to all of your accounts in AWS Organizations centrally. AWS SSO also includes built-in SAML integrations to many business applications, such as Salesforce, Box, and Office 365. Further, by using the AWS SSO application configuration wizard, you can create Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) 2.0 integrations and extend SSO access to any of your SAML-enabled applications. Your users simply sign in to a user portal with credentials they configure in AWS SSO or using their existing corporate credentials to access all their assigned accounts and applications from one place.

Please, check out some [features](https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/features/) offered by this service. There are a lot of benefits using roles instead of users. In my point of view, with AWS SSO, AWS itself facilitates the use of roles.

---

The only disadvantage I found is that every time I need to use AWS CLI, I need to access AWS SSO portal, copy the credentials and paste in my terminal because credentials expires after some time. But in the end, this disadvantage is small compared to the security that this process offers - if my computer is stolen, AWS CLI couldn't be accessed because of credentials expiration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Pedro. About copying credentials, you can use bash alias to run a script to switch role. I found the solution here very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128348/execute-terraform-apply-with-aws-assume-role